# Install Opencv on Cygwin

Tags: opencv, cygwin

I'm trying to install OpenCV on Cygwin. I have to use it because I built a NodeJS-app with the opencv-module. Now Im trying to run it on Windows.

Well, I installed Cygwin and downloaded the stable version of OpenCV for Linux.

I did: `cmake ~/opencv`

And when I'm trying make in the new directory, I got

```
$ make
[  0%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[  0%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core
[  0%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/system.cpp.o
cc1plus: Warnung: Kommandozeilenoption »-Wmissing-prototypes« ist gültig für C/ObjC, aber nicht für C++ [standardmäßig aktiviert]
cc1plus: Warnung: Kommandozeilenoption »-Wstrict-prototypes« ist gültig für C/ObjC, aber nicht für C++ [standardmäßig aktiviert]
/home/user/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/system.cpp: In Funktion »std::string cv::tempfile(const char*)«:
/home/user/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/system.cpp:523:13: Fehler: »close« wurde in diesem Gültigkeitsbereich nicht definiert
     close(fd);
             ^
Im globalen Gültigkeitsbereich:
cc1plus: Warnung: nicht erkannte Kommandozeilenoption »-Wno-unnamed-type-template-args« [standardmäßig aktiviert]
modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/build.make:632: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/system.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/system.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:798: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:136: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone know how I can install OpenCV on Cygwin or why I got these errors?

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you directly with a solution as this issue arises a lot with opencv & nodejs but I want to inform you that you should read the following issues in the node-opencv repository hopefully it helps:

https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/issues/35 
https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/issues/83

Additionally it looks like there is a fork of node-opencv with information about how to configure opencv, node-opencv etc. It looks like the pkg-config package is necessary.

Here 
https://github.com/notcoffeetable/node-opencv